# How to convert "Tue Feb 27 2024 16:35:30 GMT+0800" String to ZonedDateTime type

Tags: java, datetime

I want to convert "Tue Feb 27 2024 16:35:30 GMT+0800" String to ZonedDateTime type

I use `new ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(new Date("Tue Feb 27 2024 16:35:30 GMT+0800").toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"))`

but `new Date()` is Deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `DateTimeFormatter` and trying this?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "Tue Feb 27 2024 16:35:30 GMT+0800";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
        ZonedDateTime shanghaiTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"));
        System.out.println("Parsed ZonedDateTime: " + shanghaiTime);
    }
```

Comment: That should be `OffsetDateTime`rather than `ZonedDateTime`. No time zone is involved in that input text.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter).toZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"));`